# .conf file to redirect naked domain to page

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd.conf

I have a Craft CMS site, which has generated a specific page–let's call it "domain.com/page-x"–and I want to edit a .conf file for a new domain to redirect domain2.com straight to this page.

Thing is that since it's not a flat file, I can't use `DocumentRoot` to point directly to it in the server, so I've used `Redirect permanent`, but I'm not sure if that'll work at intended:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain2.com
  ServerAlias www.domain2.com

  Redirect permanent / domain.com/page-x

  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/website.lc-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/website.lc-error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way:

```
Redirect permanent / http://domain.com/page-x/
```

1. Always include the scheme (http/https)
2. Always match slashes in source and target.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!